# Change the attributes of all files in a drive partition

Tags: delphi

To change the attribute of a file is easy with `FileSetAttr`.

I want to change the attributes of all files located on any partition ("D:" for example).
For the search function I tried:

```
procedure FileSearch(const PathName, FileName : string) ;
var 
  Rec : TSearchRec;
  Path : string;
begin
  Path := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(PathName) ;
  if FindFirst (Path + FileName, faAnyFile - faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
    try
      repeat
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Path + Rec.Name) ;
      until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
   finally
     FindClose(Rec) ;
   end;
```

But how can I use this to traverse the entire drive?

Comment: And the question is... ?

Answer (score 3):

You will indeed need to iterate across the entire drive setting attributes file by file. You will need to modify the code to recurse into sub-directories. And obviously you will actually need to call the function that sets attributes.

The basic approach looks like this:

```
type
  TFileAction = reference to procedure(const FileName: string);

procedure WalkDirectory(const Name: string; const Action: TFileAction);
var
  F: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(Name + '\*', faAnyFile, F) = 0 then begin
    try
      repeat
        if (F.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) then begin
          if (F.Name <> '.') and (F.Name <> '..') then begin
            WalkDirectory(Name + '\' + F.Name, Action);
          end;
        end else begin
          Action(Name + '\' + F.Name);
        end;
      until FindNext(F) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(F);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I've written this in a generic way to allow you to use the same walking code with different actions. If you were to use this code you'd need to wrap up the attribute setting code into a procedure which you pass as `Action`. If you don't need the generality, then remove all mention of `TFileAction` and replace the call to `Action` with your attribute setting code. Like this:

```
procedure WalkDirectory(const Name: string);
var
  F: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(Name + '\*', faAnyFile, F) = 0 then begin
    try
      repeat
        if (F.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) then begin
          if (F.Name <> '.') and (F.Name <> '..') then begin
            WalkDirectory(Name + '\' + F.Name);
          end;
        end else begin
          DoSetAttributes(Name + '\' + F.Name);
        end;
      until FindNext(F) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(F);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Expect this to take quite a while when you try to run it on an entire volume. You'll want to do your testing on a directory containing only a few files and a couple of sub-directory levels.

Also, be prepared for your code that modifies attributes to fail for some files. You cannot expect to perform volume wide operations without sometimes encountering failures due to, for instance, security. Make your code robust to such scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for answer friend,

in delphi 7 ,
    TFileAction = reference to procedure (const FileName: string) 
does not exist yet, but I could adapt the second function according to my need.
The following code allows me to search all files in a partitition and put them attribute NORMAL:

  

     if SetFileAttributes(PChar((Name + '\' + F.Name)),          FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL) then
        SetFileAttributes(PChar(Form1.Edit1.Text),FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN );
      


**Thank you my friend**